# How to get keys and values from a dictionary within a list within a dictionary

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I would like to get the values from a list within a dictionary. I get the following json data structure when I make an Oanda REST-API request.

When I use the get function I can access the dict and the keys and its values from "trades" and "lastTransactionID", but do not know how to get the list items which are in the "trades" key.

I would really appreciate if you could help me to get this running

Works 
    print rv.get("trades")

Does not work
    print rv.get("trades").get("financing")

```
{
  "trades": [
    {
      "financing": "0.0000", 
      "openTime": "2017-11-08T17:21:49.533679739Z", 
      "price": "1.15901", 
      "unrealizedPL": "-0.0001", 
      "realizedPL": "0.0000", 
      "instrument": "EUR_USD", 
      "state": "OPEN", 
      "initialUnits": "1", 
      "currentUnits": "1", 
      "id": "2046"
    }, 
    {
      "financing": "0.0000", 
      "openTime": "2017-11-08T17:19:27.343697147Z", 
      "price": "1.15905", 
      "unrealizedPL": "-0.0001", 
      "realizedPL": "0.0000", 
      "instrument": "EUR_USD", 
      "state": "OPEN", 
      "initialUnits": "1", 
      "currentUnits": "1", 
      "id": "2044"
    }
  ], 
  "lastTransactionID": "2046"
}
```

Thanks for your help and kind regards

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate over the list:

```
for trade in rv.get("trades"):
    print trade.get("financing")
```

`print rv.get("trades").get("financing")` doesn't work because `rv.get("trades")` returns a list of dictionaries. Those dictionaries are the ones with the `"financing"` key.

Comment: Trades is a list with two components. It could also be: rv.get("trades")[0].get("financing") and rv.get("trades")[1].get("financing")

Comment: @fernand0 correct, still better to iterate though, because for another request, the api might return a different number of trades.

Comment: Correct @Bahrom iterate seems a more general approach.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate over the list:

Demo [here](https://ideone.com/5m8KKv)

```
 data = {
      "trades": [
        {
          "financing": "0.0000", 
          "openTime": "2017-11-08T17:21:49.533679739Z", 
          "price": "1.15901", 
          "unrealizedPL": "-0.0001", 
          "realizedPL": "0.0000", 
          "instrument": "EUR_USD", 
          "state": "OPEN", 
          "initialUnits": "1", 
          "currentUnits": "1", 
          "id": "2046"
        }, 
        {
          "financing": "0.0000", 
          "openTime": "2017-11-08T17:19:27.343697147Z", 
          "price": "1.15905", 
          "unrealizedPL": "-0.0001", 
          "realizedPL": "0.0000", 
          "instrument": "EUR_USD", 
          "state": "OPEN", 
          "initialUnits": "1", 
          "currentUnits": "1", 
          "id": "2044"
        }
      ], 
      "lastTransactionID": "2046"
    };

    for d in data['trades']:
        print(d['openTime'])
```

This returns:

```
2017-11-08T17:21:49.533679739Z
2017-11-08T17:19:27.343697147Z
```

Answer (score 0):

`rv.get("trades").get("financing")` did not work because, `trades` value is not a dictionary but a list. You can check the type of it by doing `type(rv.get('trades'))`. So the correct way is

```
rv.get("trades")[0].get("financing")
rv.get("trades")[1].get("financing")
```

So you need to iterate over the list as

```
for item in rv.get('trades'):
    print(item.get('financing'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another neat alternative would be to use list comprehension, which will allow for a one-line solution:

```
[trade.get("financing") for trade in rv.get("trades")]
```

Note that this is not better than @Bahrom answer, just more pythonic in my opinion.